# How to limit Youtube buffering to few min a head

Tags: internet, bandwidth, youtube

I watch quite a bit of online streaming on broadcast site like JTV and often I end up watching past broadcasts which are saved on the server... like youtube videos let's say. Problem is those videos are often 2hours long and more (one I am wtching now is 6hrs). I end up watching 20-30 mins of the video but the player will buffer the whole thing... I mean I have a 60mbps connection and these are 1080p videos you do the math... I also have a limit on my d/ls per month from my provider and I end up busting it.

I cannot seem to find a way to limit the buffer size or time in the player ... cannot find a solution on the internet anywhere. I went through the settings and all ... but the only fix I can think of it to limit my bandwidth with I net limiter program but still if I pause the video for 30min or an hour it will keep downloading... anyways I don't want to micro manage my browser's bandwidth.